# Is the sum of two singular matrices also singular?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, examples-counterexamples

If $A$ and $B$ are $n \times n$ singular matrices, is $A+B$ also singular?

Comment: If $C$ is a matrix, and $A$ is singular, and $C-A$ is singular, is $C$ singular?

Comment: mixedmath has already shown a very nice example. As a note of interest, the sum of two singular matrices will always be singular if the ranks of the two matrices do not exceed or equal $n$ in total (as the rank is sub-additive).

Answer (score 14):

No. Split up the identity matrix.

Comment: The sum is never singular? Or it sometimes is and sometimes isn't? If A=B, then I guess the sum must be singular

Comment: @AaronMcDaid  Sometimes is singular, sometimes not.

Answer (score 2):

> The sum of two singular $n × n$ matrices **may be** non-singular.

**For example**, consider two $2 × 2$ matrix $A=\begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 
\end{pmatrix}$ and $B=\begin{pmatrix} 
1 & -1 \\
-1 & 1 
\end{pmatrix}$

Here $\det A = 1-1=0$ and $\det B=1-1=0$

So both the matrix $A \quad \text{and} \quad B$ are singular matrices.

Now $A+B =\begin{pmatrix} 
2 & 0 \\
0 & 2 
\end{pmatrix}$

$\det (A+B)=4\neq 0$

Hence $A + B$ is non-singular.